# Replace a line in file using wildcard in Python

Tags: python

So hopefully I havent overlooked the correct answer, but...
In keeping with the foo bar theme.
If I have a file that looks like this:

```
blah boo who
bar blah blah
bar blah blah
foo some other chars
bar blah
black sheep
```

I want to be able to **replace the line that starts with or includes `'foo'`** and replace the whole line with out knowing the following stuff.

My current code is nasty but works, is there a way to do it without loading the file and in a loop? or at least more efficiantly than this?

```
filein = open("file", "r")
fileout = open("file.tmp", "w")
for line in filein:
    if line.startswith("foo"):
        fileout.write( "foo"+"my new numbers")
    else:
        fileout.write( line.replace('', '') )
filein.close()
fileout.close()
os.rename("file.tmp", "file")
```

Comment: This doesnt work for strings containing foo...

Comment: why fileout.write( line.replace('', '') ) and not just fileout.write(line) ?

Comment: And what is supposed to happen if the string starts with 'food'?

Answer (score 1):

```
from fileinput import FileInput
with FileInput(files="file", inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        if "foo" in line:
            line = "foo"+"my new numbers"+"\n"
        print(line, end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with regular expressions and the file can fit in memory then this should work:

```
file = open("file", "r")
data = file.read()
file.close()
data = re.sub(re.compile("^(.*)(foo)(.*)$",re.MULTILINE),'foo my new numbers',data)
file = open("file1", "w")
file.write(data)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

a much shorter code can be:

```
import os
with open('file') as f1,open('file.tmp','w') as f2:
    lines=[x if 'foo' not in x.split() else "foo my new numbers\n" for x in f1]
    f2.writelines(lines)
os.rename("file.tmp", "file")
```

**or if the file is huge:**

```
import os
with open('data1.txt') as f1,open('file.tmp','w') as f2:
    for x in f1:
        if 'foo' in x.split():
            f2.write("foo my new numbers\n")
        else:
            f2.write(x)
os.rename("file.tmp", "file")
```

Comment: this uselessly build the whole new file contents in memory instead of streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Other options:
     If "foo" in text.split()
Or: 
    if re.sub(r'foo\b', text)